# How would I upload image after fileReader to firebase storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an image to firebase storage that must be blob or file and I was wondering how could I do that after using filereader?

```
function image(file, idOfImage){
    var fr = new FileReader();
    var imgCar = document.createElement('img')
    imgCar.id = idOfImage
    fr.onload = function () {
        imgCar.src = fr.result;
    }
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    document.body.append(imgCar)
}
// sometime later... I might call uploadImage() if user wants to save this image or other image...
// (I am calling image() a couple of times so multiple images on window)
function uploadImage(idOfImage){
    var image = document.getElementById(idOfImage)
    storage.ref('...').put(image); // I get error since not blob or file
    //storage.ref('...').put(image.src); // I get same error since not blob or file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first of all, the file you place in the image function **is a blob**. So what you should do is have it either stored somewhere or just use whatever variable you placed in as the file param. This way you can use it in the `uploadImage()`. For example:

```
// This is for the examples sake, but you need to save the file you give to image() somewhere (e.g. the variable below)
var imageBlob = {};

function image(file, idOfImage) {
  imageBlob = file;
  var fr = new FileReader();
  var imgCar = document.createElement('img');
  imgCar.id = idOfImage;
  fr.onload = function() {
    imgCar.src = fr.result;
  }
  fr.readAsDataURL(file);
  document.body.append(imgCar)
}
// sometime later
function uploadImage() {
  storage.ref('...').put(imageBlob); // I get error since not blob or file
}
```

If you are uploading using the `<input type="file">` method then you can just do the following in `function uploadImage`:

```
function uploadImage() {
  // This will get the first uploaded file and upload it to firebase storage
  // All files uploaded are actually blobs (it extends the blob object)
  storage.ref('...').put(input.files[0]);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. I don't want to always uploadImage() since I want the user to select the image to be uploaded so sometimes images won't need to be uploaded.

Comment: OK, so let me see if I'm getting this right, the user uploads an image and then has to pick to upload it or not? Correct?

Comment: @Rekd Also, please give more information on how the app works and more code please, so that I know how exactly to help, yes?